# MySQL return array of results ordered by another subquery count

Tags: mysql, sql, apache

I have two tables, `tagdefinitions` and `tags`. `tagdefinitions` stores the ID of the tag, and it's name. Here is a sample of `tagdefinitions`:

```
ID   Name
1    Survival
2    Prison
3    RPG
4    Creative
```

The `tags` table stores records of where that tag was used. Each individual use is identified by serverid. Sample:

```
ID   Serverid   tagid
1    3          3
2    4          3
3    4          1
4    2          4
5    2          2
```

My query needs to return the most popular tags from `tagdefinitions`, ordered by the COUNT of records in `tags` grouped by `tagid`, if that makes sense. In the samples given above, the `tagdefinitions` should be returned in the following order:

```
3,1,2,4
```

This is because 3 was the most common, and then the rest simply ordered ascending by integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
   d.ID, 
   max(Name) as Name
from tagdefinitions d
join tags t on d.ID = t.tagid
group by d.ID
order by count(t.ID) desc, d.ID
```